# keeping radio button checked in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a real hard time keeping radio buttons checked after submitting a form!

this question has been asked several times and I did follow some instruction and finally got one of the radio buttons checked after submitting the form. but it doesn't work for the second radio button!

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$postRadioName = '';
if (isset($_POST['ship']) || '7' == $_POST['ship']) {
    $postRadioName = ' checked="checked"';
}else{

    if (isset($_POST['ship']) || '12' == $_POST['ship']) {
    $postRadioName = ' checked="checked"';
    }

}
?>
```

and this is my form :

```
<form id="radios" name="radios" method="post" action="order.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label>UK Shipping £7 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="7"<?php echo $postRadioName;?>  onclick="this.form.submit()">
    </p>
    <p>
<label>International Shipping £12</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="12"<?php echo $postRadioName;?> onclick="this.form.submit()">
    </p>
</form>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to :

### PHP :

```
<?php
$postRadioName = '';
if ('7' == $_POST['ship']) {
    $postRadioName7 = ' checked="checked"';
}else{

    if ('12' == $_POST['ship']) {
    $postRadioName12 = ' checked="checked"';
    }

}
?>
```

### HTML :

```
<form id="radios" name="radios" method="post" action="order.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label>UK Shipping £7 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="7"<?php echo $postRadioName7;?>  onclick="this.form.submit()">
    </p>
    <p>
<label>International Shipping £12</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="12"<?php echo $postRadioName12;?> onclick="this.form.submit()">
    </p>
</form>
```

by putting  `||` between `isset($_POST['ship'])` and `'7' == $_POST['ship']`, if `$_POST['ship']` exists, the if condition will return true, and the else part does not executes (even if  `$_POST['ship']==12` ).

Comment: nope, that did work.. still only checks one of the radio buttons.

Comment: You're echoing `$postRadioName` for both buttons, so if one is `checked`, so is the other one. Try different variables names

Comment: @sbeliv01 is right. look at the update, then your code will be okay

Answer (score 1):

First of all... you are using `||` in `if` functions... that basically means `OR`. And it should be `&&`, that means `AND` ...

`if (isset($_POST['ship']) || '7' == $_POST['ship'])` means... `if $_POST['ship'] is defined or has value of 7`... has no sense... will always return true, as far as any option is selected, won't even check the value of 7, because when using `||` it checks the fist condition, and if it's true, doesn't even check the second one.

Second thing... `$postRadioName = ' checked="checked"';` just leave `$postRadioName = ' checked';` - `checked` attribute doesn't have value. It simply is or is not. Same thing with `selected`.

Comment: +1 for || mention. The thing is that if you click the 12 button, your script NEVER gets into the else part of the statement, because it meets the first part "isset($_POST['ship']) ", since it is OR, it gives it to the 7